# my cucumber tests are not able to execute when i use runner class

Tags: bdd

I have two feature class in framework, and now I am not able to run MenuTest.resources feature class.I have checked multiple times whether my feature file should not have any error but no luck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess, you are not implement the step definitions for those 3 stories. So that you are getting missing step definitions. Kindly implement them in a class file then try executing it.

Comment: The issue is resolve the issue was in feature file. I have given a space in browser function.Thanks